# Link to OS X framework with boost build

Tags: c++, macos, boost, frameworks, boost-build

How do I link to an OS X framework using boost build? I have tried the following (in Jamroot):

```
frameworks_directory = "/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/" ;

lib CoreFoundation
:
: <file>$(frameworks_directory)"CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation"
:
: <include>$(frameworks_directory)"CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/" ;

exe Test : main.cpp CoreFoundation ;
```

However this produces the following error (shortened for space):

```
error: target { /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation. } has no type
```

I presume this is because the CoreFoundation file does not have an extension, and so boost-build is unable to deduce its type. Is there any way to explicitly specify the type of a file, or to in some other way link to a framework on OS X ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way:

```
exe Test : main.cpp : <framework>CoreFoundation ;
```

This is of course assuming you are using the "darwin" toolset. And have set it up correctly such that it knows about all the SDKs you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

The following works, but assumes that you are building using a compiler which supports the "-frameworks" linker option:

```
alias CoreFoundation : : : : <linkflags>"-framework CoreFoundation" ;

exe Test : main.cpp CoreFoundation ;
```

This is a pretty reasonable assumption, given that you want to link to a framework!